# How to form FTP URL using absolute path for FileZilla server?

Tags: ftp, url

I need to write a file to FileZilla FTP server hosted in Windows operating system using absolute path. The path in which I need to write the file is `C:\Test\Batch_File\count\`. The home or root path is set to `C:\Test\Batch_File` When I use relative path like `ftp://ftp.example.com/count` the FTP transfer works fine. I want the user to connect using the absolute path, something similar to the one like `ftp://ftp.example.com/C/test/Batch_File/count`. I know using the URL as `ftp://ftp.example.com/count` is the best way but I just want to experiment this. The client from which I am connecting is IBM DataPower appliance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no magical way to simply configure FileZilla FTP server to allow an access to a whole system. For a good reason, you actually do not want to do this in general. **Particularly giving even read-only access to `C:` (system) drive is a huge security risk.**

You can configure it drive-per-drive though.

- First add a fake root/home folder and point it to some empty physical path (say `C:\empty`) and set the folder read-only.
- Then add virtual path `/X:` for each `X:` drive you want to make accessible (though using simple `/X` might be better, some FTP clients may not like the colon).

And now you can use an FTP path like the `/X/foo/bar` (or the URL `ftp://ftp.example.com/X/foo/bar`) to access the `X:\foo\bar`.

[image]